# Custom action bar content partly hidden by options menu item

Tags: android

I've got a custom action bar and an options menu. The action bar shows everything if only 1 options menu item is set to `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`:

[image]

If one more menu item is set to "ifRoom", the TextView containing battery percentage and the Bluetooth icon disappears:

[image]

The part covered with the blue rectangle is the app title and it always stays. Just to clarify: the battery percentage and the Bluetooth icon are not options menu items, but they are inside the custom action bar. The thing I don't get is, why does the options menu "trim" the action bar, if all items are set to `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`.

Options menu code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_button_config"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_button_config"
        android:icon="@drawable/outline_tune_24"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_button_reg_rw"
        android:title="Register R/W"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_vert_black_24dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_button_info"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_button_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Custom actionbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/battery_level_textview_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_battery_unknown_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="-3dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:text="@string/value_unknown"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/custom_actionbar_title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/custom_actionbar_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/custom_actionbar_title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ble_disconnected_iv"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ble_disconnected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/battery_level_textview_main_activity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/battery_level_textview_main_activity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/battery_level_textview_main_activity"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ble_connected_iv"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ble_connected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/battery_level_textview_main_activity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/battery_level_textview_main_activity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/battery_level_textview_main_activity"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_connected_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/custom_actionbar_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/unknown_fw_version"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Action bar configured in activity:

```
        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mCustomActionBar = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        TextView mActionbarTitle = mCustomActionBar.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_title);
        TextView mActionbarSubtitle = mCustomActionBar.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_subtitle);
        mActionbarTitle.setText(deviceName);
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomActionBar);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Toolbar in activity's layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    ...
```

Any idea, how can I prevent the custom action bar to be trimmed by the options menu items?

Comment: not sure what the problem is. What content is hidden that shouldn't be?

Comment: If 2 options menu items are shown with "ifRoom", the battery percentage and the Bluetooth icon in the action bar is not shown. If only 1 options menu item is shown, the complete action bar is displayed, as it should always be.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want to control the order of the icons? Use android:orderInCategory

Comment: No. The battery percentage is inside the custom action bar, and it's "pushed out" or "trimmed" by the 2nd options menu item. I don't get it why the options menu does this to the action bar, when options menu items are set to "showAsAction="ifRoom". I want the complete action bar to be displayed all the time. (The battery percentage and the Bluetooth icon are not parts of the options menu)

Comment: *I don't get it why the options menu does this to the action bar* because your menu doesn't know that you have a custom layout in the toolbar and what the contents of that layout are. It only takes into account the toolbar title/subtitle when checking if there is room for the icons

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing it out! I guess putting the battery percentage and the Bluetooth icon into the options menu as a custom menu item and set it to always show, would be the best solution.